# Akka Actor Props factory

Tags: akka, actor

Akka and I are getting to know each other.

From : [Akka 2.3.6 (current) Actor Recommended Practice](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#actorselection-scala#Props)

These is an example actor called DemoActor :

```
class DemoActor(magicNumber: Int) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case x: Int => sender() ! (x + magicNumber)
  }
}
```

In *Recommended Practices* section of the doc it states : *"It is a good idea to provide factory methods on the companion object of each Actor which help keeping the creation of suitable Props as close to the actor definition as possible."* Which they do like this :

```
object DemoActor {
  def props(magicNumber: Int): Props = Props(new DemoActor(magicNumber))
}
```

*Question* : **What is the difference between specifying the factory for props method like :**

```
object DemoActor {
  def props(magicNumber: Int): Props = Props(classOf[DemoActor], magicNumber)
}
```

In case you missed it, the difference was the argument to  the Props constructor :

```
new DemoActor(magicNumber)
```

**VS**

```
classOf[DemoActor], magicNumber
```

From the same akka documentation page a bit further up in the [Props section](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Props), it also mentions when using `Props(classOf[ActorWithArgs], "arg1"`):
"The presence of a matching constructor is verified during construction of the Props object, resulting in an IllegalArgumentEception if no or multiple matching constructors are found."

That's good, isn't it?!?....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> That's good, isn't it?!?....

Yes, but it is even better if the error can be caught during compile time. The advantage of invoking the constructor directly is that the compiler will catch the problem of no matching constructor instead of an exception being thrown at runtime.

An interesting thing about the `Props` `apply` method is that when you write:

```
Props(new DemoActor(magicNumber))
```

the constructor of the actor is not invoked immediately when the Props instance is created. The constructor invocation is passed *by name* rather than *by value*. You can see this in signature of the `Props` `apply` method:

```
def apply[T <: Actor](creator: ⇒ T)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): Props
```

Notice the right arrow in the creator parameter. This allows the creator construction to be postponed, and potentially executed in another process for remote actors.

A potential hazard here is if the `new` operation closes over the scope and captures a value that is not intended to be serialized or is not serializable, thus making the Props object also not serializable. This is why the documentation recommends doing this in the companion object of the actor—to minimize the risk of closing over data that is not intended to be serialized.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the great answer. You gave me a oh-i-see moment and a little bit more confidence with akka. Thanks for pointing out the apply signature on the Props will be operating as a call-by-name. I originally thought in the back of the mind that the `classOf[DemoActor]` was avoided because of performance (given that from my past experience in Java class lookups were expensive). Compile time error raising in my case is good, I'll leave the *dynamic* lookups for special occasions when I really need it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: A call-by-name parameter is a `scala.Function0` at runtime. How does Akka serialize the function object?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe that the bytecodes are actually transferred and then loaded on the remote side. It only works if there is no context captured by a closure that is non-serializable. If you really want to know how it is done, I would suggest asking it as its own question.

Comment: I came across this really nice blog post that exemplifies @EricZoerner's answer: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/03/akka-best-practices-defining-actor-props/