# What is wrong if we pass reference to props?

Tags: scala, akka

The Akka documentation says this about props:

> Declaring one actor within another is very dangerous and breaks actor
>   encapsulation. Never pass an actor’s this reference into Props!

Why is `system.actorOf(Props(new SellActor(100)),"new_actor")` considered bad?

I went through [Akka Actor Props factory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26707337/1358676) and this [article](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/understanding-akkas-recommended-practice-for-actor-creation-in-scala) , but I am still unable to understand what is *wrong* with it. My code runs fine even when I pass the reference. Can you give a small code example showing the problem?

**Update**: From the answer given I understood its relevance from actor lifecyle. But what if I dont have any parameters to pass to the Actor object. For example,

```
system.actorOf(Props(new SellActor()),"new_actor")
```

is also considered a bad practice. What is the problem if we create one actor object inside another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an actor fails and needs to be restarted, the actor system needs to know how to do that.  When you use `Props(new SellActor(100)`, you've hidden the parameter value of `100` by handling it yourself.

If, instead, you declare *how* to create instances of the actor, the actor system will know exactly what it needs to do when recreating an actor - i.e. create an instance of `SellActor` with a constructor argument of `100`.

Even when you don't have parameters, you introduce some potentially major issues.  From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/actors.html#Props):

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED within another actor:
// encourages to close over enclosing class
val props7 = Props(new MyActor)
```

> This method is not recommended to be used within another actor because it encourages to close over the enclosing scope, resulting in non-serializable Props and possibly race conditions (breaking the actor encapsulation).

Comment: What does it mean "close over"?